# Append element AFTER load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code

```
$(".test_init").click( function(){
    var win = $(this).next(".test_wrap").find(".test_drop");

    if ($(win).html().length)
        $(win).empty().hide("fast");
    else {
        $(win).load("URL");
    }
});
```

Which returns me some html form without close button

I wish to add close button using such method without adding it in every-single function

```
$('*[class*="_drop"]').change(function() {
    $(this).append($('<a />', {
        class: 'close-drop',
        click: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("test");
        }})
    );
});
```

But nothing happens - i can't understand why close button doesn't appends

```
<div class="test_wrap relative">
  <div class="test_drop absolute"></div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fppfyey7/10/

Comment: Maybe you should use .click instead of .change

Comment: What does the HTML look like? A code snippet (demo) would be helpful.

Comment: You could redefine jQuery's `load` method to call the normal method and then call your function.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fppfyey7/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (isn't good enough, still works)

```
$('*[class*="_drop"]').ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<a onclick="$(this).parent().empty().hide(\'fast\');" class="close-drop"></a>');
});
```

If here will be better solution, will mark it as answear!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your CSS, not with your JS. The button is appended but you are hidding it with your style.

For example in this fiddle I append a button with your JS code and your CSS:

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/fppfyey7/11/)

Now, in this one, I just remove your `absolute` and `relative` classes:

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/fppfyey7/12/)

Comment: Yup, button appended at start, but when you press init, button disapears!
Because load() overwrites everyting inside...

Comment: This is the load() function behaviour. You can use `$.get()` instead, and `append()` the result, something like `$.get("ajax/test.html",function (result) { $("#element").append(result);});`

Comment: In that case in every ajax/test.html i can physicaly add close button.
The reason i asked this question to avoid every-single line changes. 
ATM there is no difference to use your code (change all load on get) and add close button in files from where i get form.
I've got more then 1k *_init and *_drop and every load contains its own form

Comment: You can do the `get` to your url (/echo/html/) and append the result to your `win` var. Is the same that the `load()` function but appeding instead of overriding.